# Jquery: Mirror one text input to another

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to have one text field autopopulate with whatever the other text field has being typed into it.

How do I go about this?

Thank you!
Hudson

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Short and simple:

```
$('#idfield1').keypress(function() {
    $('#idfield2').val($(this).val());
});
```

or to bind it to several events in order to update it also if it loses focus:

```
$('#idfield1').bind('keypress keyup blur', function() {
    $('#idfield2').val($(this).val());
});
```

Reference: [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/), [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

**Update:**

Due to, for me, mysterious reasons, when the **first** character is typed in, it is not set in the other input field. Has anyone any idea? ;)

It works though by using `keyup` (`keydown` also produces the same strange result).

Comment: You probably want to update on blur as well to capture cut/paste events.

Comment: @tvanfosson: You are right. I thought about blur first, but then I had the word "mirror" in my mind and thought it should really be synchronous... fixed.

Comment: Strange thing happens. it seems the mirror is one character behind. For example if I type "hello person", the other box reads "hello perso". any ideas?

Comment: @atwellpub: Mmh interesting. Actually I have no idea *why* . But it works for me using `keyup` instead of `keypress` ;)

Comment: I would put both keyup and keypress with the blur in the bind.  This handles the first as well as the multi-with key held down.

Comment: Great!, keyup does the trick. Now another question, and this I believe is a little trickier, how can I prevent mirroring if input 1 already has content?

Comment: @atwellpub: Can you clarify this please?

Comment: For clarification, if my input box 1 has the text "hello" in it, and I type "goodbye" in my input box 2, "Goodbye" does not replace "Hello", but if Input box 1 is empty, whatever is typed in input box 2 will display in input box 1.

Comment: @atwellpub: So in my example it would be that if if `field2` is already populated it should not be updated, right?

Comment: Well, I believe we have the same idea, but the way I have it mapped out is if field1 is populated, feild1 being originally bound to whatever is typed into field2, then the binding between field1 and field2 is nulled. But if again field1 becomes blank, then whatever is typed into field2 also appears in field1.

Comment: @atwellpub: Is it possible that both fields have the same value and field1 should **not** be updated? If **not** then you can just check whether field1 contains the same value as field2 minus the last character. If it does, it should be updated (because then, field1 is either empty or got already updated).

Comment: Thank you very much that helped me solve it! Final code: 

$('#id_query').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {
     var a = $('#id_campaign_name').val();
     var b = $('#id_query').val();
     b = b.slice(0, -1);
     
     if (a==b)
     {
      $('#id_campaign_name').val($(this).val());
     }    
   });

Comment: Using keypress leads to the input to be updated to be 1 key behind. This might be because when the key is pressed, the value isn't yet put into the text for input 1, and hence not present in input2

Comment: Is there any way that doesn't require copy-pasting the whole source every time a key is pressed?

Answer (score 7):

Dustin Diaz has written a wonderful mirror for Twitter Widget using jQuery

```
$.fn.mirror = function (selector) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $selector = $(selector);
        $this.bind('keyup', function () {
            $selector.val(($this.val()));
        });
    });
};
```

Use it like

```
$('#source_text_id').mirror('#destination_text_id');
```

Answer (score 6):

For an alternative:

```
$('#idfield1').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() 
{  
      $('#idfield2')[0].value = $(this)[0].value; 
});
```

or

```
$('#idfield1').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() 
{  
    $('#idfield2').val($(this).val()); 
});
```

For more recent version of jQuery you can also use `.on`

```
$('#idfield1').on('keyup keypress blur', function() 
{  
      $('#idfield2').val($(this).val());  
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple: http://jsfiddle.net/brynner/KnXJc/

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="one">
<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="two">
```

jQuery

```
$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    console.log( "ready!" );

   /*  $( ".checking" ).blur(function() {
          alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
        }); */
        $(".formula_open").click(function(){
            getval();
         function getval(){
        var schedulenameexpression= $('.idfield1').val();
        var res = schedulenameexpression.split(/[\s()+*-/]+/);
        var i,text,substri,newitem;

        for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            text = res[i];
           substri = text.substr(6);
            var name ="schid_"+substri;
            var schname = $('#'+substri).val();
            console.log( schname );
            schedulenameexpression = schedulenameexpression.replace("schid_"+substri, $("#"+substri).val());
        }
         $('.idfield2').val(schedulenameexpression);
        }

    $('.idfield1').bind('keypress keyup blur propertychange', function() {
        getval();

});
});
});
```