# show/hide div depening on input value

Tags: jquery, html, input, hide, show

I want to show `div#cool` when user will type `"cool"` in input field or `div#good` when user will type `"good"` and so on. Everything should work in real-time.

Comment: Are those just 2 examples, and any ID should work, or only those?  And what happens when the input changes, should they hide again?

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Created a Github Gist for it: http://gist.github.com/488611 - thanks for the comments, keyPress should indeed have been keypress. I've never had reliability issues with it myself?

In this case, we're assuming that all divs are in a parent element #divs. so they're hidden when the user changes the input.

Note: untested, so it may not work turn-key, but the gist is right.

Comment: I noticed that `keyPress` does not work reliable in all browsers.

Comment: @Felix Kling: interesting, I thought `keypress` (lower case!) is the most reliable key event crossbrowser. `keydown` & `keyup` may have more issues on that topic. Can you provide any further information or was it just sarcastic because of the uppercase 'P' ?

Comment: @jAndy: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977428/jquery-mirror-one-text-input-to-another/2977449#2977449). For some reason `keypress` did not work properly (the first key press was not detected). But I only tested it in Firefox and now in `3.6.7` it seems to work. Or the reason for this problem was something else.