# Showing one text box value in another text box while user type the value to the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the value from one text box and add it to another using jQuery dynamically when user is typing the value to the text box? can someone please explain the method if there is any such thing?

regrds,
Rangana

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: Mirror one text input to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977428/jquery-mirror-one-text-input-to-another)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/ZLr9N/?

```
$('#first').keyup(function(){
    $('#second').val(this.value);
});
```

Its really simple, actually. First we attach a `keyup` event handler on the first `input`. This means that whenever somebody types something into the first `input`, the function inside the `keyup()` function is called. Then we copy over the value of the first `input` into the second `input`, with the `val()` function. That's it!

Comment: yes that is the exact one i needed , thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi @YiJiang i am working the same method of add the dynamic textbox but my need is straight opposite of this post. My need is first textbox value is not equal to second text value, if is same show alert the value is already exist. Could you help me how to achieve this.. I have sample data in jsfiddle link - jsfiddle.net/6yMNt/6

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#textbox1').keypress(function(event) {
    $('#textbox2').val($('#textbox1').val() + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
});
```

This will ensure that `textbox2` always matches the value of `textbox1`.

**Note:** You can use the `keyup` event as others have suggested but there will be a slight lag possibly.  Test both solutions and this one should 'look' better.  Test them both and hold down a key or type real fast and you will notice a significant lag using `keyup` since `keypress` triggers before the `keyup` event even happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#from').keyup(function(event) {
      $('#to').text($('#from').val());
    });

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="from" rows=10 cols=10></textarea>
<textarea id="to" rows=10 cols=10></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textbox1").blur(function(){$('#textbox2').val($('#textbox1').val()});
}
```

Action will perform on blur of textbox1.

Comment: Avoid answering to an already solved question unless you have a better solution