# How to autopopulate a textbox with data we entered in previous textbox in C# .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

i have two textbox in a form and will be typing firstname and lastname in that two textbox

what i want is if i type a name in first textbox and do tab or mouseclick to next textbox i want the matching lastname of the firstname
to be automatically populated

how to do this... i have written the below coding but am not able to find which textbox event will be appropriate to do this..
please someone clarify my doubt

```
if (LastNameTextBox.Text == "")
{
  ACSCLN = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
  ORCMND13 = new OracleCommand("Select LASTNAME from VMS_VISITOR where FIRSTNAME='" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "'", CON);
  DR22 = ORCMND13.ExecuteReader();

if (DR22.HasRows == true)
{
  while (DR22.Read())
  {
    ACSCLN.Add(DR22["LASTNAME"].ToString());
  }

  LastNameTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
  LastNameTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
  LastNameTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ACSCLN;
}
LastNameTextBox.Focus();
```

Comment: Your SQL code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Dai is correct.  You should change this to use a parameterized query.

Comment: Please always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: The best way would be to use javscript. When you use jQuery you can attach all event which you want.
Btw. your variable names are unreadable

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593679/showing-one-text-box-value-in-another-text-box-while-user-type-the-value-to-the

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about TextBox events, than, if you use Windows Forms - there is **Leave** event, and in WPF - **LostFocus** event.