# onKeyUp with one input field affecting another with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

I've got 2 input fields. They are both currently populated.

```
Input 1 = "Name"
Input 2 = "Name says this: blah blah blah"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to bind an onKeyUp event to both of them so that when Input 1 is changed, it will also change the value of input 2.

For example:

```
Input 1 = "Bla"
Input 2 = "Bla says this: blah blah blah";
```

I was thinking a regex, but what if it searched for "bla" on input 2, and returned 4 occurrences? That's why I was thinking of just maybe getting rid of everything after the first space in Input 2 and always replacing that value.

This is what I was kind of thinking of doing:

```
        $('#input-1').bind('keyup', function() {
        $('#input-2').val().append($('#input-1'));
    });
```

Obviously that code doesn't work, but can anyone point me to the right direction? Should I make a variable and put it in the beginning of the input box (of input 2)?

**EDIT:**

This is the code that ended up working, which also doesn't delete the additional info if there is any in input-2's box:

```
var name = $('#input-1').val();
var text = " wanted to tell you something;

$('#input-1').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {
   name = $(this).val();
$('#share-message').val(name + text);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: Mirror one text input to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977428/jquery-mirror-one-text-input-to-another)

Comment: Wow, can't believe that didn't popup as a suggestion. Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('#input-1').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {
    var input2  = $('#input-2').val();
    var input1   = $(this).val();
    $('#input-2').val(input2+input1);
  });
```

Comment: Aside from the missing parenthesis, this helped. Thanks.