# Javascript to update a textbox based on the input of another textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox

I basically want to use javascript to have 2 textboxes that depend on each other. For example if I input a number x in textbox1, I want textbox2 to instantly update with x*2. If I input x into textbox2, I want textbox1 to be automatically updated with x/2. These values will always be numbers.

Edit: so here is my html file. Can anyone give me a hint to why it's not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#text1").keyup(function(){
            $("#text2").val($(this).val() * 2);
        });
        $("#text2").keyup(function(){
            $("#text1").val($(this).val() / 2);
        });        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="text1" size=3 maxlength=6>
    <input type="text" name="text2" size=3 maxlength=6>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds awesome, let us know how it turns out.  If you have questions if/when you try/fail, post back here with your sample code.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yKrJn/

Comment: Something similar was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977428/jquery-mirror-one-text-input-to-another

Answer (score 2):

In the very simple case, this should do it ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/ETYgD/)):

```
// in a <script>:
window.update = function() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one'),
      two = document.getElementById('two');    

  two.value = parseInt(one.value) * 2;
}​

<!-- in your HTML: -->
<input id="one" type="text" onchange="update();" />
<input id="two" type="text" />​
```

Comment: If you're planning to do even slightly more DOM manipulation, however, you would be *much* better off adopting a framework such as jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textbox1").onkeyup(function() {
    $("#textbox2").val($(this).val() * 2);
});

$("#textbox2").onkeyup(function() {
    $("#textbox1").val($(this).val() / 2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to test out the exact code you'll need for this right now, but the basic idea is to put an OnKeyUp event on each box and modify the other box through the script (using getElementById or whichever method you like)

I will try to put together some code when I can if someone else doesn't get to it first.

Answer (score 0):

Use an onchange event or a jquery change callback to update the other boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In the this case, this should do it : http://jsfiddle.net/du09jhpd/

```
window.update = function() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one'),
      two = document.getElementById('two');    

  two.value = parseInt(one.value) * 2;
}
window.update1 = function() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one'),
      two = document.getElementById('two');    

  one.value = parseInt(two.value) / 2;
}
```