# Return id from nested_attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have an edit view in rails with a number of input boxes from nested_attributes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :item_prices, :class => "col-sm-2" do |ff|%>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :store_id %>
            <div class="col-sm-8 input_cc_size">
                <label><%= ff.object.store.name %></label>
                <%= ff.text_field :regular_price, :class => "form-control input_cc_size_nested", :value => (number_with_precision(ff.object.regular_price, :precision => 2)) %>
            </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

I would like dynamically in javascript when i type a value in the first box the rest to take this value. 
I found this reference [Jquery: Mirror one text input to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977428/jquery-mirror-one-text-input-to-another)
and I am trying to do something like that in javascript. How can i return the ids of the nested attributes in javascript and iterate through them? If the ids where standard I could do something like

```
$('#item_item_prices_attributes_0_store_id').bind('keypress blur', function() {
    $('#item_item_prices_attributes_1_store_id').val($(this).val());
    $('#item_item_prices_attributes_2_store_id').val($(this).val());
});
```

but with the nested attributes I don't know how to do that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the actual HTML, not just the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AlexAtNet thanks for taking the time to answer!

What i did was to iterate with a for loop through the desired ids. I added also a hidden field in my form to count the prices so the ids I needed for the for loop. 
My js is:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("item_item_prices_attributes_0_regular_price.bind("change", function(){
        stcount = document.getElementById('count_stores').value;
        for (var i=0; i< stcount; i++){
            $("#item_item_prices_attributes_"+i+"_regular_price").val($(this).val());
        }
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the tag name, not to the id:

```
$('.form-group input:eq(0)').bind('keypress blur', function () {
  $('.form-group input:gt(0)').val($(this).val());
});
```

should copy the value of the first input to all other inputs within the element with the class `form-group`.

Comment: You might want to read about the jQuery selectors:http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/